# Popover Border Shadow and Alignment Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There are two main issues why I'm writing for help today. As you can see that the popover is wrapped in a column alongside a text. So the preview I expect to be someone thing Text1 (popover) and 405 on the right because it has float-right property. Now I failed to understand why is it not coming next to where it should come and displaying on the top of "Text1".

Secondly, how do I add Popover border shadow?

Regards,
Bill

```js
// Bootstrap Popover
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
  trigger: 'focus'
})
```

```css
.popover-holder .popover {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border: 1px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #737373;
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  z-index: 9;
}

.popover-questionmark {
  margin: -2px 0px 3px 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.popover:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<center>
<div class="col-9 pl-0 float-left">
  <div class="float-left">Text1</div>
    <div class="popover-holder">
      <a tabindex="0" class="popover" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="top" data-content="Hello World"><span class="popover-questionmark">?</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-3 float-left">
  <div class="checkout-total-trip float-right">405</div>
</div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, wrap your whole `column div` element inside of a `row div` element. You don't need to use `absolute` position to stick your thing next to text just add `display` property. Try below code -

```js
// Bootstrap Popover
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
  trigger: 'focus'
})
```

```css
.text-div,
.popover-holder {
  display: inline-block;
}

.popover-holder .popover {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border: 1px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #737373;
  position: relative;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  z-index: 9;
}

.popover-questionmark {
  margin: -2px 0px 3px 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.popover {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0 2px 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="text-div">Text1
      <div class="popover-holder">
        <a tabindex="0" class="popover" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="top" data-content="Hello World"><span class="popover-questionmark">?</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="checkout-total-trip float-right">405</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The position: absolute is loading by default through bootstrap. How do I remove it? And I was looking for border shadow only, something like this: http://prntscr.com/n450wr

Comment: I have updated my answer. Also, you can overwrite any CSS with your own.

Comment: And lastly, how do I remove the border color and keep the border shadow only?

Comment: If you want to make border transparent then just put the CSS `border-color: transparent` and for shadow, you can use `box-shadow` property.

Comment: border-color: transparent doesn't work. Can you make it work in the snippet, please?

Comment: try using `border-color:none`

Comment: Still doesn't work. I tried almost everything and that's why I came back for you for a solution.